# É possivel comentar varias linhas de uma só vez em VBA?

Tags: vba

Existe o equivalente a `/**/` de [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) para comentar em [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) em vez de usar plicas em cada linha

```
    'Function Prodcet30(a As Double, b As Double) As Double
    'If a = 0 Then
           ' MsgBox ("Por favor introduza o valor a")
           ' Exit Sub
           ' Exit Sub

   ' End If
         ' If b = 0 Then
            'MsgBox ("Por favor introduza o valor b")
         ' Exit Sub
    'End If
   ' Prodcet30 = a * b
   ' End Function
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existe, mas ele não funciona como no C#, ele é uma barra de ferramentas, você ativa assim:

1. Vai em exibir > Barras de ferramentas > Editar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Para comentar, você seleciona o código que você quer deixar em comentário e clica na opção, "Comentar bloco".
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
3. Para retirar o comentário, precisa selecionar onde quer retirar e clicar no botão, "Remover comentários do Bloco".
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Nunca soube... Show!! valeu